# Classifying data contained in a file with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have a file (corresponding to one and only one person) with n columns (or classes) containing different data: Name (class 1) , address(class 2) , number (class 3), username (class 4), etc (class n). I wish to classify an incoming data as one of these classes.

Example : If I get an incoming data to be : "John Smith" ..my ML model should classify it as : "Name". If i get "Ronald Reagan Avenue 3456" : the output should be "address" and so on.

I wonder if the naive Bayes model in ML would be suitable for such task?

I have been looking at the naive Bayes model that make me skeptical : It assumes independence between features . Would that be a problem in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as a Text Classification model, where the text data is "Ronald Reagan Avenue 3456", "Gorgit", "17000", etc and the field names can be the classes that you need to classify.

You can use transfer learning to fine tune the model on your data or just code

Comment: Hello..and thanks for the answer. What are your thoughts about Naive bayes or KNN when solving this problem?

Comment: The Data we are talking here about is sequential data and naive bayes and KNN are preferred for tabular data. And about the independent features, it is not always possible to have independent features, we will definitely have some correlation, so we drop the columns with high correlation (keeping only 1 of the correlated features.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question a bit : This data/classes (i.e. name, address, number) are rather tabular than sequential as this is not a text (ie not Gorgis is at Ronald Reagan Avenue 3456) but comma separated/tabulated data that needs to be classified

Comment: Example, the following data is (lets say) on a csv file : {John smith; Ronald Reagan Avenue 3456, gorgit@homtail.com}. When i put this inside a classifier, it should output : Name, address, mail

Comment: What did you try to say about the independet/correlation by the way?

Comment: You need to convert the data into some numbers, right? How do you plan to do so? The option that i see is to tokenize the words and prepare the data similar to text data.

Comment: This conversion can be done with Countvectorizerz/bag of words..etc

Comment: Anyways..my question to you is (assuming we can convert to numbers and so on) : How could these classes be correlated (dependent) at all..they do not have anything to do with each other..do they?